# Standard for embedding location in SMPP?

Tags: geolocation, sms, smpp

Is there a standard (or even an often-used convention) for embedding phone location information like latitude and longitude in an SMS conversation?  I've just read  the SMPP 3.4 spec, which has nothing specific for phone location, but a few possibilities come to mind:

- Add location to a custom TLV parameter
- Put it in the message_payload TLV of a data_sm operation

If there's no standard, does anyone have a convention that has worked well for them?  I'd rather not hack my own solution if there are lessons to be learned from others.

Answer (score 0):

There are at least two competing standards.

- [OGC 09-142r1](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&ved=0CCYQFjAA&url=http://portal.opengeospatial.org/files/?artifact_id=36261&ei=USj9UpT8POHnsASB_4HICQ&usg=AFQjCNF6rk8oTQCzsP70_1JXZxA9Qgaxig&bvm=bv.61190604,d.cWc)
- [GeoSMS](http://geosms.wordpress.com/the-geosms-standard)